# Pipes between three children

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'd execute this command `ls -al / | tr a-j A-J | tr k-z K-Z` and I'd create three children from father process.

I know that I've to open two pipes, let father waits for all his children (closing all the pipes) and in the children I've to

- close STDIN on the first child
- close STDOUT on the first pipe and STDIN on the second pipe, on the second child
- close STDOUT on the third child

Now, this is my code. If I run it with just two children, it works. But, if I try to run it with three children, it doesn't work.

```
//  command is ls -al / | tr a-j A-J | tr k-z K-Z

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int fd1[2];
int fd2[2];
pid_t pid = 0;

pipe(fd1);
pipe(fd2);

pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    close(fd1[0]);
    dup2(fd1[1], 1);
    close(fd1[1]);

    execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", "/", NULL);
}

pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    close(fd1[1]);
    dup2(fd1[0], 0);
    close(fd1[0]);

    close(fd2[0]);
    dup2(fd2[1], 1);
    close(fd2[1]);

    execlp("tr", "tr", "a-j", "A-J", NULL);
}

pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
    close(fd2[1]);
    dup2(fd2[0], 0);
    close(fd2[0]);

    execlp("tr", "tr", "k-z", "K-Z", NULL);
}

close(fd1[0]);
close(fd1[1]);
close(fd2[0]);
close(fd2[1]);

while ((pid = wait(NULL)) != -1);

exit(0);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You never close any of the pipe ends in the parent.  The child that is reading from the pipe is waiting for *all* write ends of the pipe to close, but the parent is still holding one end open.  Close it.

Comment: I close pipes at the end. I've to close them at the beginning?

Comment: `tr` is not going to terminate until all the write ends of the pipe are closed.  If the parent `wait`s for `tr` to terminate, it must close the end of the pipe before it waits, or the two process will be deadlocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *pipe2()* with close_on_exec flag set. The following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int fd1[2];
  int fd2[2];
  pid_t pid = 0;

  pipe2(fd1,O_CLOEXEC);
  pipe2(fd2,O_CLOEXEC);

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    dup2(fd1[1],1);
    execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", "/", NULL);
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    dup2(fd1[0],0);
    dup2(fd2[1],1);
    execlp("tr", "tr", "a-j", "A-J", NULL);
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    dup2(fd2[0],0);
    execlp("tr", "tr", "k-z", "K-Z", NULL);
  }

  close(fd1[0]);
  close(fd1[1]);
  close(fd2[0]);
  close(fd2[1]);

  while ((pid = wait(NULL)) != -1);

  exit(0);
}
```

It is possible to use *pipe()* call also, but you should take care to close descriptors everywhere manually, which is error prone (you demonstrated that by posting this problem ;-) ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int fd1[2];
  int fd2[2];
  pid_t pid = 0;

  pipe(fd1);
  pipe(fd2);

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    close(fd1[0]);
    dup2(fd1[1], 1);
    close(fd1[1]);

    execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", "/", NULL);
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    close(fd1[1]);
    dup2(fd1[0], 0);
    close(fd1[0]);

    close(fd2[0]);
    dup2(fd2[1], 1);
    close(fd2[1]);

    execlp("tr", "tr", "a-j", "A-J", NULL);
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) {
    close(fd1[0]);
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd2[1]);
    dup2(fd2[0], 0);
    close(fd2[0]);

    execlp("tr", "tr", "k-z", "K-Z", NULL);
  }

  close(fd1[0]);
  close(fd1[1]);
  close(fd2[0]);
  close(fd2[1]);

  while ((pid = wait(NULL)) != -1);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include a link to the relevant man page (e.g. [`pipe2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)).

Comment: Thank you. But, what if I've to use just `pipe()` and not `pipe2()`?

Comment: @FedericoCuozzo: If you use `pipe()` instead of `pipe2()`, then you need to close the unused pipe descriptors before you exec children.  In practice, that means that you've use `dup()` or (more likely) `dup2()` to duplicate pipe descriptors to standard input or standard output, you need to close _all_ of the file descriptors from the pipes before you use `execvp()` or whatever. Note that `execlp()` is of limited value; you must know (an upper bound on) the number of arguments at compile time — `execvp()` is the more general interface.  For your immediate purposes, `execlp()` is OK.

Comment: In my first code, I close the unused pipes before I exec children, but the code doesn't work.

Comment: @FedericoCuozzo: you do not close fd1[0] and fd1[1] in your last child creation. Try it: your program, with *pipe()* call, works well with this modification.